# Serializing entity's custom fields in sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius, jmsserializerbundle

I have extended entity user.

```
namespace MyShop\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
```

Next, I want to expose `email` and exclude, for example, `id` field.
How should I config these conditions?

I found this [solution](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/8708) and add config in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            myshop-user:
                namespace_prefix: "MyShop\\CoreBundle\\Entity"
                path: "@MyShopCoreBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
```

But sylius doesn't see my `MyShop/CoreBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Model.User.yml`

```
MyShop\CoreBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    xml_root_name: user
    properties:destroyyamlfile
        id:
            expose: false
            type: integer
        email:
            expose: true
            type: string
```

I deliberately destroy it but framework works well and doesn't see my wrong editions.

So how should looks my configs in  `app/config/config.yml` and `Model.User.yml`??